# How to retrieve all the collection's and sub collection's document in a single fetch from cloud firestore for android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-retrieval

Following is path from where I want to retrieve all of data present in different documents.

/EAT(collection)/eat/Celebrity(collection)/celebrity/Actor(collection)

And there are different sub-collections instead of Celebrity like sports person and others.And also sub-collections like actress instead of Actor.
So I want to fetch all the data from all documents at a time using loop or iterator in Android Java.

Answer (score 0):

Queries in Firestore are shallow: they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from a top-level collection and subcollections in a single query.